# Two numeric variables concatenation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code below

```
var i=2;
var j=2;
concat(i,j);
```

Result should be 22

Comment: Where is jQuery in this?

Comment: or the question, for that matter

Comment: This is not a stackof question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the clumsy String Constructors, you can simpy do:

```
i+""+j;
// or
""+i+j
```

else

```
String(i) + String(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
function concat(i, j)
{
  return String(i) + String(j);
}
```

#### Code: http://jsbin.com/orimih/2/edit

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/orimih/2

Answer (score 0):

convert it to a string ...using `String()`

```
alert(String(i) + String(j));
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/YK39h/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         alert(ConcatIntegerValue(2,2));

});

 function ConcatIntegerValue(i,j)
  {
        return String(i) + String(j);
   }
```